# Getting the service principal for an Azure Automation Account connection using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-automation

I know how Get-AutomationAccount can be used to retrieve the connection details internally while running a runbook within an automation account.

However, what if I want to be able to report on the service principal being used by the AzureRunAsConnection external to a runbook job?

I've tried something like the following:

```
$automationAccount = Get-AzAutomationAccount -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $name
$conn = $automationAccount | Get-AzAutomationConnection
$conn.FieldDefinitionValues
```

However, the FielDefinitionValues hashtable has nothing in it? I was expecting to see things like tenantId, ApplicationId, etc.

I can get this information via the portal by clicking on:

> AutomationAccount > Run as accounts > Azure RunAs Account

or by

> AutomationAccount > Connections > AzureRunAsConnection

But can't see how I can get this info for the RunAs Account from PowerShell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HA! Never mind. It turns out you need to provide the name of the connection in the cmdlet. Otherwise, it doesn't fill in certain properties in the output... :/ I would have expected it to just output all connections with all their properties. Maybe a bug?

Comment: So changing the line above to: $conn = $automationAccount | Get-AzAutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `$conn = $automationAccount | Get-AzAutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"`.

> Maybe a bug?

It is not a bug, because the two commands call different REST APIs.

When using `$conn = $automationAccount | Get-AzAutomationConnection`, it calls this rest api [`Connection - List By Automation Account`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/connection/listbyautomationaccount), the details of `fieldDefinitionValues` will not be exposed, it will always be `null`. You could check the [sample response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/connection/listbyautomationaccount#examples) or catch the request of the powershell with fiddler.

[image]

When using `$conn = $automationAccount | Get-AzAutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"`, it calls this rest api [`Connection - Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/connection/get). The `fieldDefinitionValues` will include the properties you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You answered this yourself in the comments. But just to stop this question coming up as unanswered:

```
$conn = $automationAccount | Get-AzAutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd never have thought the same command could call more than one api.